# How do I open a (Mercurial) patch file in a human-readable format (preferably with kdiff3)?

Tags: linux, mercurial, diff, kdiff3

The Mercurial command

```
hg diff > mypatchfile
```

compiles a "patch" file representing the differences between the working directory and the last commit. Opening this file as plain text results in a presentation of the changes that is quite difficult to read. I want to open this file in a diff tool for a clearer presentation of the differences.

I know that the diff tool `kompare` can do exactly this, using the command

```
kompare mypatchfile
```

But while its presentation is certainly more readable than the plain text format, I find it lacking.

I much prefer `kdiff3`. Can this tool open patch files? The command

```
kdiff3 mypatchfile
```

doesn't work. Instead, the patch file is just opened in plain-text format in the left panel, while the right panel is empty. But it seems that `kdiff3` *should* be able to open patch files, because I can just write

```
hg extdiff -p kdiff3
```

and get exactly the presentation I want. However, I don't see how I can get similar results with a previously exported patch file. Any suggestions?

(I would also appreciate recommendations for other diff tools that can open and display patch files in a readable format.)

Answer (score 0):

1. You can't do it easy (but can try to do it with *some* tricks for *some* patches)
2. `hg extdiff -p kdiff3` does **NOT** visualize custom patch, but (read carefully [Extdiff extension wiki](https://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/ExtdiffExtension)) only show in dual-window mode *difference between two revisions* (see difference in terms) - Working Dir and parent in simplest case (and sources for diffing are **full files from relevant revisions**)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just tying to visualize diff output, right ? There's a tool [xxdiff](http://furius.ca/xxdiff/) that might be useful with few caveats. `extdiff` is an external diff, that is instead of using Mercurial diff, another program is used to do the `diff` of two revisions. You can even use linux `diff` command as an `extdiff` for Mercurial.